# Does android:largeHeap decrease process priority?

Tags: android

I have two identical apps:

1. AppA declares `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest
2. AppB declares `android:largeHeap="false"` in manifest

In a hypothetical scenario when both of these apps run on the same device, consume the same amount of resources, have the same current process priority (let's say both run service processes), does having `android:largeHeap="true"` flag affect how OS decides which one to kill first?

Looked up documentation here, but there is not much: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you do not. Process priority is managed by the your OS. If your app is running in the foreground, it will run with foreground priority. If your app is not running in the foreground, it will not run with foreground priority.